# Is it possible to render the output of a javascript script as a jpeg instead of a web page?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, io

A fantastic programmer by the name of Cameron Beccario created a web page- http://www.earth.nullschool.net- that maps out global wind vectors based on current weather models. I need to somehow get the output on the site in the form of an image sequence or an MPEG-4, but each frame needs to be 4096x2048 px. Obviously, a screenshot isn't going to work. I have access to the source code, which is on Github, and the code seems to be a group of javascript libraries interacting with the one javascript object "earth" that Mr. Beccario wrote himself (along with some CSS and such that doesn't seem related to my problem). My goal is to project this map onto a six-foot spherical screen (don't ask), and I can't modify the software that converts a flat map into a spherical projection. So essentially, I need to project the contents of a webpage onto a really big screen in high resolution, somehow.

What I've tried (that hasn't worked):

- Going through the source code and trying to insert a script to redirect the output of the javascript into an image file. According to my more knowledgeable coworkers, this won't work, because a library called d3.js is doing the actual rendering and it isn't as simple as "output of javascript becomes input of d3, I write a simple script to put that input into a jpeg file instead."
- Various software that takes screenshots.
- Finding a library that can take Javascript input and deal with it outside the context of a webpage. I'm not sure this would work even if I did find one, and in any case, I haven't yet.

What I want to know:

- Is there a library that can replace d3 in this code, and render the javascript as a high res image?
- One of my coworkers suggested "wrapping the map in a browser." He didn't get a chance to explain what he meant, does anyone know if this would be an effective way to project a detailed video or image sequence?
- Does anyone know of any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any words of wisdom.

Comment: There are a couple of dozen questions/answers dealing with rendering D3-generated SVGs to JPG, PNG, PDF, etc. I'm sure you'll be able to find them with a little bit of search.

Comment: Yes, there are. However, none of the ones I've encountered deal with getting a higher resolution than the screen is providing in the first place, or with a constantly re-rendering source. My problem is that this website is not creating SVGs at all; it's using the HTML5 canvas features to constantly redraw the layers in the div (it has three). I might be missing something relevant; if so, if you could suggest a specific question that might be helpful, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I originally was going to recommend wkhtmltopdf, which can generate images directly from a site with JS support and can specify device settings (including a massive screen). However, I don't think that will work for your purposes, since the image source is constantly changing.  I really think your best best would be to find a similar tool that can be used to create screencasts from a website.

Barring that, there is a round-a-bout approach that might get you what you want.  Using a free virtual machine, you can set up a dummy machine with a high resolution screen (e.g. 4096x2048) and then use that to do a screen capture to mp4.

Comment: Thanks tobylaroni. I'll try the second one; I've been looking for software or a script that would accomplish the first, and not finding anything.